# Neo4jClient - How to check if property exists

Tags: neo4jclient

I'm having trouble converting the following Cypher query to the Neo4jClient syntax.

MATCH n
WHERE NOT (HAS (n.User)) OR n.User = "username"
RETURN n

This is what I currently have with the addition of some relationship logic and the omission of the HAS logic

```
var results = Client.Cypher
               .OptionalMatch("(result)-[connection:Connection]-(result2)")
               .Where((Result result) => result.User == username)
               .Return((result, connection, result2) => new Neo4jResultSingle()
               {
                   SearchedNode = result.As<Node<Result>>(),
                   RelationshipConnection = connection.As<RelationshipInstance<Connection>>(),
                   Relationship = connection.As<RelationshipInstance<ConnectionRelationship>>(),
                   RelationshipedNode = result2.As<Node<Result>>()
               }).Results.ToList();
```

Comment: Can you post the exact cypher query you are trying to translate to C#?

Comment: To add the HAS logic you can write `.Where("NOT HAS(n.User)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at a combination of your original query and your C# maybe the following might help?

```
var results = Client.Cypher
           .Match("(result)-[connection:Connection]-(result2)")
           .Where("WHERE NOT HAS(n.User) OR n.User = {username}")
           .WithParams(new { username = username })
           .Return((result, connection, result2) => new Neo4jResultSingle()
           {
               SearchedNode = result.As<Node<Result>>(),
               RelationshipConnection = connection.As<RelationshipInstance<Connection>>(),
               Relationship = connection.As<RelationshipInstance<ConnectionRelationship>>(),
               RelationshipedNode = result2.As<Node<Result>>()
           })
           .Results
           .ToList();
```

This rewrites your WHERE clause to include both the HAS and username logic, whilst parameterising it to cache the query plan and protect against injection.

Answer (score 11):

`HAS` was superseded by `EXISTS()`

From the latest docs: [Property existence checking](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/where/#property-existence-checking)

```
MATCH (n) WHERE EXISTS(n.User) RETURN n
```

for opposite match add `NOT` before

```
MATCH (n) WHERE NOT EXISTS(n.User) RETURN n
```

Comment: The property existence syntax `... exists(variable.property)` is no longer supported. Please use `variable.property IS NOT NULL` instead.

Answer (score 10):

In [Neo4j 4.3](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/where/#property-existence-checking),

> The exists() function has been deprecated for property existence checking and has been superseded by IS NOT NULL.

So please use

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE n.User IS NOT NULL 
RETURN n
```

OR

```
MATCH (n) 
WHERE n.User IS NULL 
RETURN n
```

In your code specifically,

```
var results = Client.Cypher
       .Match("(result)-[connection:Connection]-(result2)")
       .Where("WHERE n.User IS NULL OR n.User = {username}")
       .WithParams(new { username = username })
       .Return((result, connection, result2) => new Neo4jResultSingle()
       {
           SearchedNode = result.As<Node<Result>>(),
           RelationshipConnection = connection.As<RelationshipInstance<Connection>>(),
           Relationship = connection.As<RelationshipInstance<ConnectionRelationship>>(),
           RelationshipedNode = result2.As<Node<Result>>()
       })
       .Results
       .ToList();
```